# need Delete operation of BST for my program

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
package com.Binary_Search_Tree;

public class HackerRank 
{
    HackerRank left , right;
    int data;
    
    public HackerRank(int data)
    {
        this.data = data;
    }
    
    public void insert(int value)
    {
        if (value <= data) 
        {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new HackerRank(value);
            }else {
                left.insert(value);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new HackerRank(value);
            }else {
                right.insert(value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In my delete operation I can go to the value but I can not make it null because its an integer value. do anyone can suggest something better which fits my code.

Comment: Do you want someone to provide you with a `delete()` method?

Comment: Which delete? There are cases in deleting a node i.e. if it has no child, simply delete, if has one child or if it has two childs

Comment: you can't simply remove a node, while deleting a node, you need to remember even after deleting the node, the tree must contain the BST property. do you need any help to understand any further ?

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the `data` field as it is, removing the `left` and `right` references as well as other references that point to the object you want to delete should suffice.